# Ruby on Rails: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) even if provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

We *inherited a rails project* (the whole thing is based on elasticsearch). Thus, the application lists all the documents meeting the provided search criteria by a user. Imagine a facet or so, once you've selected i.e. a specific range of dates it gives you the documents that were created at that time.

We have been currently working on expanding its functionality accordingly:

> Our priority is to ***utilize the elastic query*** such that ***all
> matched*** documents by that query could be ***multiply altered*** (in
> our case, we've been trying to hide all the documents). Then we want to send the query to appropriate rake task that would take care of it.

After the button responsible for mass hiding is clicked the controller's create method gets called, thereby creating a `mass_hiding` record in database (for convenience we keep a track of hidings which would allow us to revert the mass action afterwards).

```
  def create
    mh = current_user.mass_hidings.build(params[:mass_hiding])
    mh.save!
    mass_hide(mh.query_params)
    redirect_to search_documents_path(mass_hide.search_parameters)
  end  

  def mass_hide(query)
    search = factic.create_restrictions_search(MultiJson.load(query.to_json))
    Resque.enqueue(Document::Jobs::HideDocuments, nil, search.to_scrollable.build_query)
  end
```

However, the line **3** of the create method `mass_hide(mh.query_params)` triggers the following exception once it gets executed:

> ArgumentError in Admin::MassHidingsController#create
> ***wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)***
>
> *Full trace* can be found [**here**](https://pastebin.com/mSXZRP99).

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6mZvRcp4HJuoBWMRToA2gPec9Wv8T82hiTJQ/STf1j/sDhQ+16mBW3QkRmhqlJIHKR0kvX/kqwQh205hp6RuDg==",
 "mass_hiding"=>{"serialized_query_params"=>"{}",
 "description"=>"test"},
 "commit"=>"Hide documents"}
```

Further, here is the schema representation of `mass_hiding` as well as the appropriate model:

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "mass_hidings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "serialized_query_params"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
end
```

**mass_hiding.rb**

```
class MassHiding < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :serialized_query_params, :description
  belongs_to :user

  def query_params=(params)
    self.serialized_query_params = Oj.dump(params)
  end

  def query_params
    Oj.load(self.serialized_query_params).with_indifferent_access
  end

  def self.find_or_initialize_by_user_and_query_params(user, query_params)
    self.find_or_initialize_by_user_id_and_serialized_query_params(user.id, Oj.dump(query_params))
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please share the complete error with backtrace

Comment: @Salil I've added above a link to the trace you've asked for.

Comment: The stack trace says that your error is not where you think it is.  It's not in the create method, it's inside the mass_hide method.

Comment: @MarcTalbot sorry for confusing you, I had reorganized the code a bit meaning that line numbering in the trace does not comply with the line numbering of the samples provided. Here is the [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/HiaiTEy.png) where the execution stopped.

Comment: Can you print out `mh.query_params.inspect` right before you call `mass_hide`?

Comment: @mikwat it has given me the output: `{"supplier"=>"Zariadenie pre seniorov "}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined this helper function:

```
def mass_hide(query)
```

But you are calling it with zero arguments.

First you call it with one argument, when you say `mass_hide(mh.query_params)`. That's fine.

But then on the next line you also say `mass_hide.search_parameters`. To Ruby that means `mass_hide().search_parameters`. Perhaps you meant to write `mh.search_parameters`? I'm not sure. But `mass_hide` is the method that wants 1 param, and that's the callsite where you pass it 0.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This helped me :)